# Convert a dictionary with lists of differing lengths in dictionary to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm retrieving a JSON by calling the OMDB API about a movie. I'm trying to add the JSON to another dictionary which is scraping information from [here](http://rogerebert.com/reviews/).

Dict which has the scraped information has the structure:

```
{
         'movie_title': [],
         'review_text': [],
         'review_url': [],
         'reviewed_by': [],
         'score': []
}
```

I'm dynamically adding keys to the dictionary with values as empty lists by looping over the response from the OMDB API, like so

```
api_key = ''
ombd_data = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=api_key'+'&t=Basmati+Blues&plot=full'
omdb_json = json.loads(omdb_data).content
for curr_key in omdb_json.keys():
    movie_review_dict[curr_key] = []
```

The dict now has the structure

```
{
     u'Actors': [],
     u'Awards': [],
     u'BoxOffice': [],
     u'Country': [],
     u'DVD': [],
     u'Director': [],
     u'Genre': [],
     u'Language': [],
     u'Metascore': [],
     u'Plot': [],
     u'Poster': [],
     u'Production': [],
     u'Rated': [],
     u'Ratings': [],
     u'Released': [],
     u'Response': [],
     u'Runtime': [],
     u'Title': [],
     u'Type': [],
     u'Website': [],
     u'Writer': [],
     u'Year': [],
     u'imdbID': [],
     u'imdbRating': [],
     u'imdbVotes': [],
     'movie_title': [],
     'review_text': [],
     'review_url': [],
     'reviewed_by': [],
     'score': []
}
```

I have a function which reads this URL, uses the BeautifulSoup module and adds elements to the dict. I'm also adding data from the OMBD response at the same time.

```
def read_html_page(home_page='http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews'):
    movie_details = movie_review_dict
    result = requests.get(url=home_page)
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(result_content, 'html5lib')
    wrapper_class = soup_obj.find('div', id='review-list')
    for curr_movie_dom in wrapper_class.find_all('figure'):
        movie_title = curr_movie_dom.find('h5', class_='title').a.get_text()
        movie_critic = curr_movie_dom.find('p', class_='byline').get_text().strip()  
        omdb_dict = get_omdb_data(movie_title=movie_title)
        for curr_key in omdb_dict.keys():
            if curr_key in movie_details:
                movie_details[curr_key].append(omdb_dict[curr_key])
            else:
                movie_details[curr_key] = []
                movie_details[curr_key].append(omdb_dict[curr_key])
    return movie_details
```

I'm trying to store the dict into a pandas DataFrame, but I'm getting the error

```
ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
```

That's because some attributes from the OMDB response, like 'Languages', 'Website' exist for some movies, and not for others.

I've tried

```
movie_df = pd.DataFrame(movie_review_dict)
movie_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(movie_details)
```

And am running into the same Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try appending to an empty dataframe using [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(movie_review_dict, ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: That gave the error 

'TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name'

I changed that to 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.append(movie_review_dict,ignore_index=False)

And got an empty DataFrame

Comment: The comment was to say that I tried exactly that.

And got an empty dataframe

Comment: append function does not modify the dataframe so you have to reassign it to see the new result. Try the updated one and see if it works